# Nested grid with 2 section displays inconsistent rows sizing and overlaps elements

Tags: css, nested, rows, css-grid, dashboard

I'm currently laying out a dashboard web application and decided to use nested grids.
The idea is to have the grid display 27 raws and 5 columns. The menu (1st subgrid) should span on the first column and the rest of the columns should contain the second subgrid where the content will be displayed. Let's call it main section.

Note: The main section doesn't necessarily need 27 rows. What is important is to have 3 grid areas span evenly from top to bottom on the 1st 2 columns of the main section. The rest 9 grid areas need to be displayed on the remaining columns of the main section as groups of 3 each to the main areas.

The problem:
1. However, I set up the code it seems that the rows are not equal in between the menu and main section and can't grasp why.
2. The first the last grid areas as slots also end up overlapping with each other although I set the grid areas correctly.

What I tried:
1. Setting the menu to 27 raws and the main section to 9.
2. Setting both menu and mainSection to 27 rows.
3. Giving Slot 1 to different rows ends to test how it could align with the menu.
4. Checking the code to any slightest typo.
5. Other small adjustments that I can't even remember after days of frustration. I'll follow up with updates and answers should I remember any of them.

Can someone, please, end my frustration? :(

PS: I'm having the CSS in the HTML file since I'm coding mobile (temporary limitations) and fail to set up the HTML to recognize the CSS file.

Code below.
Edit: Sorry for the misalignment in the code structure. I'm coding a g-drive file on the go on phone and tablet. It seems that “tab“ key do different things between the 2 mobile platforms.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

            <!--<div id="appTitle">protoAccounting</div>-->

    <body id="mainGrid">
        <div id="menu">

            <!--<div>-->
                <div class="menu_Item" id="menu_home">
            <div class="notify_img" id="homeLed">img</div>
                                          <div class="title" id"homeText">Home</div>
                                          <div class="submenu" id="homeSubmenu">items</div>
                                        </div>
                <div class="menu_Item" id="menu_input">
                                          <div clss="notify_img" id="homeLed">img</div>
                                          <div class="title" id"homeText">Input</div>
                                          <div class="submenu" id="homeSubmenu">items</div>
                                        </div>
                <div class="menu_Item" id="menu_database">
                                          <div clss="notify_img" id="homeLed">img</div>
                                          <div class="title" id"homeText">Database</div>
                                          <div class="submenu" id="homeSubmenu">items</div>
                                        </div>
                <div class="menu_Item" id="menu_currentMonth">
                                          <div clss="notify_img" id="homeLed">img</div>
                                          <div class="title" id"homeText">Current month</div>
                                          <div class="submenu" id="homeSubmenu">items</div>
                                        </div>
                <div class="menu_Item" id="menu_previousMonth">
                                          <div clss="notify_img" id="homeLed">img</div>
                                          <div class="title" id"homeText">Previous month</div>
                                          <div class="submenu" id="homeSubmenu">items</div>
                                        </div>
                <div class="menu_Item" id="menu_ato">
                                          <div clss="notify_img" id="homeLed">img</div>
                                          <div class="title" id"homeText">AllTimeOverview</div>
                                          <div class="submenu" id="homeSubmenu">items</div>
                                        </div>
                <div class="menu_Item" id="menu_atelier">
                                          <div clss="notify_img" id="homeLed">img</div>
                                          <div class="title" id"homeText">Atelier</div>
                                          <div class="submenu" id="homeSubmenu">items</div>
                                        </div>
                <div class="menuItem" id="investments">
                                          <div clss="notify_img" id="homeLed">img</div>
                                          <div class="title" id"homeText">Investments</div>
                                          <div class="submenu" id="homeSubmenu">items</div>
                                        </div>
                <div class="menu_Item" id="futureNecesities">
                                          <div clss="notify_img" id="homeLed">img</div>
                                          <div class="title" id"homeText">Future Necesities</div>
                                          <div class="submenu" id="homeSubmenu">items</div>
                                        </div>
            <!--</div>-->
        </div>

        <div id="mainSection">
            <div id="slot1">SLOT1</div>
            <div id="slot2">SLOT2</div>
            <div id="slot3">SLOT3</div>
            <div id="slot4">SLOT4</div>
            <div id="slot5">SLOT5</div>
            <div id="slot6">SLOT6</div>
            <div id="slot4">SLOT7</div>
            <div id="slot5">SLOT8</div>
            <div id="slot6">SLOT9</div>
            <div id="slot4">SLOT10</div>
            <div id="slot5">SLOT11</div>
            <div id="slot6">SLOT12</div>
        </div>

    </body>

<style>

body {
    font-size: 1em;
    background: silver;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#mainGrid {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, [col] 20% );
}

#mainSection div {
    border: 1px dotted black;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#menu {
    grid-area:  1 / 1 / 9 / 2;
    display: grid;
}

#menu div {
          border: 1px dotted  black;
    text-align: center;
}

#mainSection {
     grid-area: 1 / 2 / 9 / 6;
     display: grid;
}

#menu_home {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / span 1 / span 1;
}

#menu_input {
    grid-area: 4 / 1 / span 1 / span 1;
}

#menu_database {
    grid-area: 7 / 1 / span 1 / span 1;
}

#menu_currentMonth {
    grid-area: 10 / 1 / span 1 / span 1;
}

#menu_previousMonth {
    grid-area: 13 / 1 / span 1 / span 1;
}

#menu_ato {
    grid-area: 16 / 1 / span 1 / span 1;
}

#menu_atelier {
    grid-area: 19 / 1 / span 1 / span 1;
}

#investments {
    grid-area: 22 / 1 / span 1 / span 1;
}

#futureNecesities {
    grid-area: 25 / 1 / span 1 / span 1;
}

/*mainSection area*/

#slot1 {
    /*grid-area: mSlot1;*/
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / span 3 / span 2;
}

#slot2 {
    /*grid-area: mSlot1;*/
    grid-area: 1 / 3 / span 1 / span 2;
}

#slot3 {
    /*grid-area: mSlot1;*/
    grid-area: 2 / 3 / span 1 / span 2;
}

#slot4 {
    /*grid-area: mSlot1;*/
    grid-area: 3 / 3 / span 1 / span 2;
}

#slot5  {
    /*grid-area: mSlot1;*/
    grid-area: 4 / 1 / span 3 / span 2;
}

#slot6 {
    /*grid-area: mSlot1;*/
    grid-area: 4 / 3 / span 1 / span 2;
}

#slot7 {
    /*grid-area: mSlot1;*/
    grid-area: 5 / 3 / span 1 / span 2;
}

#slot8  {
    /*grid-area: mSlot1;*/
    grid-area: 6 / 3 / span 1 / span 2;
}

#slot9 {
    /*grid-area: mSlot1;*/
    grid-area: 7 / 1 / span 3 / span 2;
}

#slot10 {
    /*grid-area: mSlot1;*/
    grid-area: 7 / 3 / span 1 / span 2;
}

#slot11  {
    /*grid-area: mSlot1;*/
    grid-area: 8 / 3 / span 1 / span 2;
}

#slot12{
    /*grid-area: mSlot1;*/
    grid-area: 9 / 3 / span 1 / span 2;
}


</style>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you have an image of what this is *supposed* to look like?

Comment: I think we really need a fiddle here with a simple example

Comment: Since I'm coding on the go, I don't have a documentation set up for it. However, I have a drawing in my notepad with how it should look. I'll upload the photo. Edit: Here's the photo: https://imgur.com/a/EwSqEIr

Comment: I'm afraid what you are after is probably not possible at present with CSS-Grid as it will, I believe, require `display:subgrid" to work. There is no methodolgy at present to equalise "grids" between different elements.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I might try something with subgrid and if there is no resolution I'll consider restructuring the design. As for the Overlaping slots, do you have any ideea what could cause it? Fiddling with it started to bring me to a solution, but I didn't investigate because I was too quick to reapply the initial code. I hope that coding mobile one day will be more seamless in terms of folders administration :(

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. It was an error of copy-paste type. Had the id of the slots 4 to 6 repeating among the other slots.
It fixed both the alignment between the menu and mainSection (without subgrids or anything complex) And the overlap between the slots.